# How to make a blank page in Google Chrome at start-up?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Does Google Chrome has anything similar to about:blank page in IE and Firefox? I did not find any suitable page mentioning this?
PS: I tried about:blank but it looked like Chrome is trying to load something before showing blank page...

Comment: Google Chrome (and several from other google apps) are quite unconventionally dictator sometimes : Desktop, Mobile (Android) version or whatever.  Not only such basic things are hidden from user-options, but even inaccessible from advanced-options. They attitude to all people as noobs, as they knowingly ignore that there are "advanced" users, who just need to customize basic things, and they don't expose those settings. That's why I switched to **Opera**.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Not possible without an extension. Get this one:

Empty New Tab Page
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/empty-new-tab-page/dpjamkmjmigaoobjbekmfgabipmfilij

This extension will load a totally blank new tab and remove the `about:blank` from the location bar. Works great!

Comment: I installed it and it works fine.

Comment: If you are launching chromium for automation the '--disable-instant-extended-api' flag seems to work as add_argument to chrome options

Comment: Is it Open source? Can we trust it?

Comment: @l--marcl Blank New Tab Page URL has changed to: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blank-new-tab-page/jaadjnlkjnhohljficgoddcjmndjfdmi

Comment: For those of us who prefer and/or by policy to never install extensions, except possibly those written ourselves, please see @dess answer below.

Answer (score 39):

Summarizing all I've found for the subject, including this thread, the simple, safe and resource-effective way is to create minimal extension (as recommended by author of "New Tab Redirect" here: https://github.com/jimschubert/newtab-redirect/wiki#user-content-save-locally ):

### Minimal extension

Create two text files:

- **manifest.json** with contents:

  ```
  {
    "name": "Empty new tab page",
    "description": "Override the new tab page with an empty page, for users who don't like the original or custom new tab pages",
    "version": "1.0",
    "incognito": "split",
    "chrome_url_overrides": { "newtab": "newtab.html" },
    "manifest_version": 2
  }
  ```
- **newtab.html** with contents:

  ```
  <html>
  <body></body>
  </html>
  ```

Save the files in *empty* directory, which should not be deleted while this extension in use (eg. directory "Empty new tab page" in Documents ) and:

- Go to Chrome Extensions page (`chrome://extensions/`)
- Check "Developer mode" (upper right)
- Click "Load unpacked extension..." and point to the directory where two files was saved

Developer mode now could be turned off.

Now we've got absolutely blank new tab with absolutely blank URL field.

Note: newtab.html could be customized in a suitable way.

Comment: This works great. The only (minor) problem is that the new tab is called "Untitled" for about half a second before changing to whatever is specified in the `<title>` tag of the `.html` file (or blank if there is no `<title>`), which is annoying. As a workaround, I've just specified the `<title>` as "Untitled", but I would prefer having it be "New Tab", as it is by default.

Comment: Still valid solution in 2023/10. The only change, in **manifest.json** it's better to use `"manifest_version": 3` or else you get a warning message regarding deprecation.

Comment: Working very fine. It seems to affect Edge, Chromium and Chrome at once.

Comment: Fantastic and still valid as of 2024 (January.) Possibly extensions on the Chrome store are doing exactly (and hopefully, ONLY) this, but as a developer, my personal policy is to never install extensions. Also, because I will surely forget that I've done this, I've added the path to the extension/page to the markup as well (and to make it easier on the eyes, <body style="background-color: #444;"> )

Answer (score 10):

Did you check Google Chrome's help forum?: [Start chrome with blank page.](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=2e25c9051ac8e6f1&hl=en)

> - It's true that if you go to 'Options' > 'Basic' > 'On Startup' > 'Open the following pages' and then add 'about:blank', that chrome
>     starts with an empty page, but still, it doesn't achieve the previous
>     behaviour, because with these settings, on the address bar it will
>     appear 'about:blank', and you have to delete it..Before, (or if you
>     configure the 'Homepage' section to 'Use the new Tab page'), chrome
>     would start with a blank page, and with nothing on the address bar, so
>     you could start typing immediately the link of the page you wanted to
>     go..I know that is a small detail, but to me it makes a big
>     difference..
> - Try to use this extension. It can solve some of your concerns in my opinion: [Speed Dial](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dgpdioedihjhncjafcpgbbjdpbbkikmi)

Comment: Thanks... It seems there is no complete solution till now...

Comment: Answers with no useful information except for a link aren't really considered good answers. Please at least summarize what's on the other end of that link.

Comment: I still don't know how using a start page like Speed Dial is going to help make a blank new tab, but... for me everything takes too long - a blank page is instant.

Answer (score 8):

On the first Options tab, add `about:blank` to the set of pages to open when you open chrome. Change setting to `On startup: Open the following pages...`. Done.

Comment: Thanks for answering... Mehper's link is what I was looking for.

Comment: Just to add... When Google Chrome opens, the text 'about:blank' will not be selected, so that you can just start typing your search query in the address bar. You can easily overcome this by simply pressing Esc key, which will select that text and you can start typing your query.

Answer (score 3):

The thing with about:blank is that Chrome puts your cursor in front of the "about", so you have to delete it before you can begin typing.

I noticed that if you set your homepage to **`javascript:void()`**, it still goes to about:blank, but the cursor is no longer in the address bar. So when you click the address bar, "about:blank" is highlighted and you can immediately start typing over it.

Comment: it works great.

Answer (score 3):

My solution was to create the simplest of html files, a completely blank file called *index.html* in my root.

With "file:///C:/index.html" in *Open a specific page or set of pages* in *Settings*, it comes up quickly, and one click in the address bar prepares for a search.

I suppose it could be named anything.

Answer (score 2):

This "solution" is not giving you a blank page but at least you don't have to delete those ugly 'about:blank' or so in the URL bar:

'Settings' > 'On Startup' > 'Open a specific page or set of pages' > 'set pages'

then
Add a new page:  'chrome://newtab/'

I found this to be the best solution because:

- the URL bar is already empty, no need to select and delete its content every single time
- depending on your settings you have also access to your extensions, apps, Google Drive, Youtube and so on

Comment: Yes, `chrome://newtab/` is full of bookmark icons and screenshots of frequently visited sites (as of Chromium 40). That's the opposite of a blank tab: loading an actual website takes less time!

Answer (score 1):

If you open up chrome.dll - you will see that the "New Tab" page is actually loaded via Javascript from an HTML page embedded inside of chrome.dll as a resource. You can remove it (replace it with nothing).

1. Using [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/), open chrome.dll.
2. Use Find Text (Ctrl+F) to search for "NewTabScriptStart". The location will be something like BINDATA\771 or BINDATA\768 or similar depending on your version of Chrome or Chromium variant.
3. Push Ctrl+A and Delete to delete the entire contents of the page where NewTabScriptStart was found.
4. Push "Compile Script" button at top.
5. File->Save

Now your "New Tab Page" is a blank page. In Settings, select On Startup --> "Open the New Tab Page".

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, go to Wrench->Options and set Home Page to "Use the New Tab page" and On startup to "Open the home page". Instead of getting a blank page, you'll get clickable icons for your most often visited websites.

Comment: I am strictly looking for a blank page to come up. Nothing more nothing less.

Answer (score 0):

Set "Open a specific page or set of pages" to "http:\". Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with (64-bit) Chrome v.63.0.3239.84 running on my Windows 7 Pro.

In my case even though I had added `about:blank` as the page to open under `On startup > Open a specific page or set of pages`, Chrome still opened to the Bing search home page every time I launched it.

Admittedly Bing search was my default search engine, but still in my opinion it should not have overridden the `On startup` setting.

Anyway, because Bing was my default search engine, and I did not want to set Google or any of the other ones as default, I installed the DuckDuckGo extension (from [DuckDuckGo.com](https://duckduckgo.com/)) and then removed Bing search from the browser.

Not sure if it is necessary to remove any of the other search engines, but installing the DuckDuckGo extension and setting it as default were in any case part of this resolution.

After these changes my Chrome browser now starts with the about:blank page.

(It could also be that the first opened page can also be controlled through the search engine "Modify" settings.)

Answer (score 0):

I just set it to `chrome://blob-internals/`, almost a blank page.
Or open `chrome://about/` and see a list of available pages you can choose from.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in the address bar

```
data:text/html, <html contenteditable>
```

You can save this "URL" as a bookmark so it's always a click away.
(Warning: the stuff you type on that page is not saved when you close the tab)

Answer (score -2):

```
chrome://newtab/
```

Set this as your home page. Easy as that.

Comment: This does not bring up a blank page. But the default page with most visited sites.