# Google Chrome strange address bar behavior

Tags: google-chrome, address-bar

Opening a new tab in Google Chrome normally selects the text in the address bar; as of recently it has been placing the cursor after the last character and not overwriting over when I begin to type.  Any ideas what may have changed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a blank page in Google chrome at start-up?](http://superuser.com/questions/206229/how-to-make-a-blank-page-in-google-chrome-at-start-up)

Comment: @Nemo: It isn't clear how you think that relates to what was asked.

Comment: @fixer1234, the asker wants to open a new tab and be able to immediately type the search query or URL; http://superuser.com/a/600232/283120 provides a solution which does exactly that

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you experienced with your Chrome but for me, opening a new Tab or Window results with a blank address bar and its in focus so I can type from it right away.

Comment: Until recently that was the same behavior I was having - only now it opens a new tab to the Google homepage and the cursor at the end of the http://www.google.com and my HomePage is set to the "New Tab page"