# Change Chrome New Tab Page to local file

Tags: google-chrome

All of the extensions that allow you to change the the new tab page to a local file leave the cursor at the end of the URL, meaning that every time I open a new tab I now need to type <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.

I would either like the URL bar to be blank or for all the text to be selected like in Firefox so that I can simply start typing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a blank page in Google chrome at start-up?](http://superuser.com/questions/206229/how-to-make-a-blank-page-in-google-chrome-at-start-up)

Comment: I'm not asking for an empty page. I'm asking for a specific local html file to load. Extension mentioned in that solution suffers from the same flaw mentioned above.

Comment: The [extension suggested](http://superuser.com/a/600232/283120) works in my testing (Chromium 40) exactly as in Firefox (37): I don't have to do Ctrl-A, the only difference is that there is no "Search or enter address" placeholder. You wrote "I would either like the URL bar to be blank" so that seems achieved; if that's not your goal, please edit the question. Either way, the [New Tab Redirect](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna) extension mentioned in other answers to that question can load a local HTML file as well.

Comment: The extension suggested doesn't allow you to load a local file, just a blank page, and the New Tab Redirect extension suffers from the cursor flaw. I want to load a custom html page *and* have the URL bar selected/blank at the same time.

Comment: It seems not to be possible. See [GitHub issue](https://github.com/jimschubert/NewTab-Redirect/issues/46).

Comment: Thanks for the update! It seems the answer I read on a similar question was wrong though it had upvotes. :) You may want to incorporate your findings in the question, they are useful.

Comment: It seems to be a weird limitation of Chrome. See my answer. It only works for local files.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no way to do this besides creating your own extension (see question comments for details). As it turns out, creating your own extension to do so is incredibly easy.

1. Create a new folder
2. Place the HTML file you want to load in your new tab inside it. Mine is called `new-tab.html`
3. Create another file in the folder called `manifest.json` that looks like this:

   ```
   {
     "name": "My custom new tab page",
     "description": "Overrides the new tab page",
     "version": "0.1",
     "incognito": "split",
     "chrome_url_overrides": {
       "newtab": "new-tab.html"
     },
     "manifest_version": 2
   }
   ```
4. Go to `chrome://extensions` and click the `Developer mode` checkbox on the top right.
5. Click the <kbd>Load unpacked extension…</kbd> button
6. Navigate to your folder and click select

Comment: Looks like this browser is designed to make it hard to choose your own start page. I wonder why. :P

Comment: Chrome now alerts users on every startup asking if you would like to disable locally installed extensions, so this isn't as useful as it once was. You'd have to publish your extension to the store to get around this

Comment: Chrome no longer alerts users on every startup. I've been running locally-made extensions with no issues.

Comment: This works to this day, and it is a very good tip/ answer indeed. I always used the extension, but it stopped working. New tab home pages are excellent, and also provide a bit of fun, as well. You simply open the file locally, and edit it exactly how you want. Much less hassle than putting it on the web.

Comment: Chrome shows a warning using this json: "Manifest version 2 is deprecated, and support will be removed in 2023"

Comment: Change the 2 to 3 it should work fine on the new version.

Comment: poopy dumpster browser feature, doesn't let you execute `<script>`… you'll want to create an ahk script that just points to your file, for example, on your desktop — https://pastebin.com/T0SFxHau — Chrome addon "New Tab Redirect Options" works okay...